# How to add paging capabilities to the Repeater control in ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2, sqldatasource

I have an asp.net Repeater control .I have to display only 5 rows in the repeater. I searched about it in Google but most of the resources are talking about how to do it with DataSet. In my case, I am using SqlDataSource. **So I can have paging in this Repeater control?**

ASP.NET Code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater3" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <div>
                        <table border="1">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="3">
                                        <center> <strong>Safety Quizzes Record</strong> </center>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <center> <strong>Quiz Title</strong> </center>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <center> <strong>Date & Time</strong> </center>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <center> <strong>Score</strong> </center>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>

                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <p>
                                    <%# Eval("Title") %>
                                </p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <p>
                                    <%# Eval("DateTimeComplete") %>
                                </p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <p>
                                    <%# Eval("Score") %>
                                </p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        </table>
                        </div>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" 
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT     dbo.Quiz.Title, dbo.UserQuiz.DateTimeComplete, dbo.UserQuiz.Score
FROM         dbo.employee INNER JOIN
                      dbo.UserQuiz ON dbo.employee.Username = dbo.UserQuiz.Username INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Quiz ON dbo.UserQuiz.QuizID = dbo.Quiz.QuizID
WHERE     (dbo.employee.Username = @Username)">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="Username" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**UPDATE:**

What I want is showing only 5 items in the Repeater and the others will be listed on the other pages of the Repeater. So how I can have Pagining with SqlDataSource as mentioned above.

Comment: -1 Don't change the question from under the already posted answers. If you have a different question, post it as a new question.

Comment: It is the same question. Just read it carefully before telling me what I should do and how to use this community.

Comment: Your title is misleading. It implies you want to have only five rows **total** while your real question is how to enable paging in repeater control. Next time make sure to have title matching the question and it will save you downvotes.

Comment: Read the second sentence of your question, where it specifically says that you have to display *only* five rows. I answered that question, and got downvoted for that. You can use the community how ever you like, but if you keep pissing off the people trying to help you, you won't get much help.

Answer (score 1):

The `Repeater` control does not support paging out-of-the-box.

You could however implement it but it would require you to manually code it.

I would like to recommend you to change the `Repeater` control for the `ListView` control

Differences:

- [Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8f2zez5.aspx). This control does not support paging, updating, inserting or deleting operations out-of-the-box, if you want these features you would need to manually code them.
- [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790.aspx). This is the most flexible of all data-bound controls. It's based on templates like the `Repeater` and `DataList` controls. It does support CRUD operations automatically mapping the operations agains your data source control. It does support server paging, and you can customize pretty much everything

BTW, since you are using a `SqlDataSource`, you would have to manually add paging code to your queries or store procedures, you could change that behavior if you use a `LinqDataSource` or an `EntityDataSource`

This is a simplified `ListView` markup:

```
    <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lv"
        DataSourceID="lds" DataKeyNames="emp_id"
        EnableModelValidation="false"
        EnablePersistedSelection="false" 
    >
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <br />
            <br />
            A static header
            <div runat="server" id="itemPlaceHolder"></div>
            <br />
            <asp:DataPager runat="server" PageSize="4">
                <Fields>
                    <asp:NextPreviousPagerField 
                        ButtonType="Button" 
                        ShowFirstPageButton="true"
                        ShowLastPageButton="true"
                    />
                </Fields>
            </asp:DataPager>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div style="background-color:Gray">
                First Name
                <div><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl" Text='<%# Eval("fname") %>'></asp:Label></div>
                <br />
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSource='<%# Eval("Achivements") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" Text="Select" CommandName="Select" runat="server" />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit" runat="server" />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton4" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" runat="server" />
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemSeparatorTemplate>
            <hr />
        </ItemSeparatorTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the PagedDataSource shown at link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.pageddatasource.aspx